# What is the Bind Request and how it can be established

Tags: java, http, bind

We are trying to integrate with a vendor sending http request/response. We were expecting the vendor to give us a URL to send requests to. However, the vendor said that they will not provide us with the URL instead of that they asked us to make first a "Bind Request" to be able to continue sending messages.

We already asked them about what is meant by "Bind Request" or how to send it, but the one who was responsible for making the testing with us didn't have this information and told us there is no way from his side to provide more about that. So after many searching time, we found this is somehow a floating term. So it would be grateful if someone has any information about this issue. Or even the questions that must be known from them to be able to establish this request. I only have accessible IP and a port. I even don't know if it should be handled through just a code or there should be something to be done on the network level.

Comment: Any serious product will have a written API and specification explaining these things.

Comment: Bind is fairly common terminology when talking about LDAP(but not limited to only talking about LDAP)

If you have the IP address, that IS the URL -> IP:PORT